# How to use secondary indexes for a "contains" query

Tags: rethinkdb

Rethinkdb docs has this example to improve getAll/contains queries with a secondary index:

```
// Create the index
r.table("users").indexCreate("userEquipment", function(user) {
    return user("equipment").map(function(equipment) {
        return [ user("id"), equipment ];
    });
}, {multi: true}).run(conn, callback);

// Query equivalent to:
// r.table("users").getAll(1).filter(function (user) {
//     return user("equipment").contains("tent");
// });
r.table("users").getAll([1, "tent"], {index: "userEquipment"}).distinct().run(conn, callback);
```

My questions is if there's a way to do the same but for querying with multiple tags. What would be the equivalent to make this query possible with a secondary index?

```
r.table("users").getAll(1).filter(function (user) {
    return user("equipment").contains("tent", "tent2");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably we can do this

```
r.table("users").getAll([1, "tent"]).filter(function (user) {
    return user("equipment").contains("tent2");
});
```

So build a multi index as you did, and try to `getAll` first, so that part is efficient with index, then `filter` to continue ensure that `equipment` contains array we want.